# unable to scale the path's certain children in x axis only

Tags: c#, wpf, scaletransform

My code is drawing combination of horizontal and vertical lines in wpf. I want to only scale horizontal lines.. this code is scaling both horizontal and vertical.

```
Path path = new Path();
            SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
            brush.Color = Colors.Red;
            path.Stroke = brush;
            path.StrokeThickness = 4;
             LineGeometry lineGeometry = new LineGeometry();
            lineGeometry.StartPoint = new Point(10, 100);
            lineGeometry.EndPoint = new Point(100, 100);
            LineGeometry lineGeometry2 = new LineGeometry();
            lineGeometry2.StartPoint = new Point(100, 100);
            lineGeometry2.EndPoint = new Point(100, 200);

            LineGeometry lineGeometry3 = new LineGeometry();
            lineGeometry3.StartPoint = new Point(100, 200);
            lineGeometry3.EndPoint = new Point(200, 200);
            LineGeometry lineGeometry4 = new LineGeometry();
            lineGeometry4.StartPoint = new Point(200, 200);
            lineGeometry4.EndPoint = new Point(200, 100);
            LineGeometry lineGeometry5 = new LineGeometry();
            lineGeometry5.StartPoint = new Point(200, 100);
            lineGeometry5.EndPoint = new Point(300, 100);
            GeometryGroup geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();
            geometryGroup.Children.Add(lineGeometry);
            geometryGroup.Children.Add(lineGeometry2);

            geometryGroup.Children.Add(lineGeometry3);

            geometryGroup.Children.Add(lineGeometry4);

            geometryGroup.Children.Add(lineGeometry5);

            path.Data = geometryGroup;


            var scaling = new ScaleTransform(2, 1);

            path.RenderTransform = scaling;
            canvas1.Children.Add(path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to scale the geometry, but not the Path's StrokeThickness, do not set the Path's RenderTransform.

Instead, directly transform the Geometry:

```
geometryGroup.Transform = new ScaleTransform(2, 1);
path.Data = geometryGroup;

canvas1.Children.Add(path);
```

Comment: this solution is working. I am very sorry. I am unable to understand how scaling is being done on horizontal lines only. we are scaling geometryGroup which has both horizontal and vertical lines. then how it is only scaling horizontal lines. I am grateful to you.

Comment: i am getting the required output. i want to scale horizontal ones only. the code works perfectly fine. but i am unable to understand  how this is happening. i am sorry.

Comment: It's simply transforming all points in the GeometryGroup, i.e. the X value of each point is multiplied by 2.

Comment: when I use m_scale>8 the graph disappears from the window.but if I use value of m_scale between 1 and 8 the graph is scaled perfectly. Is there some limit on ScaleTransform?

Comment: list.ForEach(a => a.Transform = new ScaleTransform(m_scale, 1));

Comment: There shouldn't be any limit.